# Jquery AJAX not firing some c# webmethods

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have been encountering a strange problem.  I am working with several AJAX calls from my page.  Some work and others to not fire their corresponding methods but rather return full HTML of page.

Here is the code that works:
JS:

```
/***************************************************************
function getBoothData():

retrieve data for site on site change or page load
/**************************************************************/
function getBoothData() {
    var location = $("input[name=siteMap]:checked").val();
    $(".desk").remove();
    //Get booth data
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./default.aspx/deskData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "location": location }),
        success: function (response) {
            siteID = location;
            data = response.d;
            showData(data.Desks);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    }); //$.ajax()
} //getBothData()
/**************************************************************
end getBoothData()
/**************************************************************/
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static DeskItemList deskData(string location)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string query = "select * from tblSiteLayout where SiteID=(select ID from tblSiteLayoutSites where UPPER(SiteName)=UPPER('{0}'))";
        query = string.Format(query, location);
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd = getCmd(query, out con);
        con.Open();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();

        var DeskList = new DeskItemList();
        DeskList.Desks = new List<desk>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            desk d = new desk();
            d.id = dr["id"].ToString();
            d.x = Convert.ToInt32(dr["x"]);
            d.y = Convert.ToInt32(dr["y"]);
            d.height = Convert.ToInt32(dr["height"]);
            d.width = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Width"]);
            d.UserLogon = dr["UserLogon"].ToString().Trim();
            d.DeskID = dr["DeskID"].ToString().Trim();
            d.Extension = dr["Extension"].ToString().Trim();
            d.Assets = dr["Assets"].ToString().Trim();
            d.computerIP = dr["ComputerIP"].ToString().Trim();
            d.RAM = dr["RAM"].ToString().Trim();
            d.HDD = dr["HDD"].ToString().Trim();
            d.SiteID = dr["SiteID"].ToString().Trim();
            d.Department = dr["Department"].ToString().Trim();
            d.deskType = (int)dr["deskType"];
            d.rotation = (int)dr["rotation"];
            d.UserName = dr["UserName"].ToString();

            // d.usrImg = dr["userImg"].ToString();

            DeskList.Desks.Add(d);
        }

        return DeskList;
    }
```

That above call works perfectly while the following function does not get called at all:

JS:

```
/***************************************************************
function fillData(obj):

Takes associated data from element and applies it to 
the edit form
/**************************************************************/
function fillData(obj) {
    //add data to element to show and edit from editData div
    $("#rowID").text(obj.data("rowID"));
    $("#deskID").val(obj.data("deskID"));
    $("#user").text(obj.data("user"));
    $("#empID").text(obj.data("empID"));
    $("#ext").text(obj.data("ext"));
    $("#dept").text(obj.data("dept"));

    var desk=obj.data("rowID");

    //retrieve user image
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "default.aspx/getImageForDesk",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{ "deskID":' + desk + '}',
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response.d;
            $("#userImg").attr('src',data);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
         error: function (resp, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            //alert("Status: " + textStatus); 
            //alert("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            var a=resp.responseText;

        },
        complete: function (resp, status){
            //console.log(resp.responseText);
            //alert(status);
        }
    }); //$.ajax()
}
/**************************************************************
end fillData()
/**************************************************************/
```

C#:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string getImageForDesk(int deskID)
    {
        string ret = "";
        //if (Convert.ToInt32(deskId) > 1)
        int deskId = deskID;

        if ((int)deskId >= 1)
        {

            string query = "select usrImage from tblSiteLayout where id=" + deskId;
            SqlConnection con = MCAIntranet.Data.Connections.ConDEV();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            byte[] img = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("./images/tempUser.png"), img);

            ret = "tempUser.png";
        }
        return ret;
        //        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {image = ret});
    }
```

For whatever reason, even though (so far as I can tell) the calling and receiving signatures are the same.  There error function just tells me that it cannot parse the returned HTML as JSON so that is useless to me.  Are there any suggestions as to where I have gone wrong on this?

Thanks

Comment: You have `type: "POST"` commented out in ajax code?

Comment: I have tried multiple things :)  That was one I was trying.  It removes the parseError status that is returned because it was trying to parse the page HTML as JSON.  Makes no effective difference otherwise.  It has since been uncommented. - Just removed comment here as well.  Thanks.

Comment: It's expecting an `int` but `desk` is probably string value. Try `var desk = parseInt(obj.data("rowID"));`?

Comment: Same problem.  I had also tried setting the receiving deskID as object with no success.

Comment: Have you tried using stringify with `desk` parsed to int?

Comment: Just removed the passed in parameter from both ends with no change so it's not the JSON passed in causing the problem.

Comment: Yes I have.  I am hoping that there is a glaring issue with my code that I have missed entirely.  But I have messed with the parameters every way I can think of to no avail.

Comment: Just reading https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquery-ajax-function-call-code-behind-C-Sharp-method/

Says that the webmethod must be static but I cannot do that since I am writing a file to the drive.  If there is another way to send an image back to the AJAX call I would happily do that.  Could not get base64 encoding to work correctly.  But I have other webmethod's which are not static but do work.

Comment: You're missing `static` from the `[WebMethod]`

Comment: How can I write a file from a static method?  And my mistake I thought I had non-static webmethods.  I do not.

Comment: You should update your question with that info, maybe someone here knows how. The problem is how to hit a non-static WebMethod with ajax, or to write a file from a static method.

Comment: Right.  I will.  Thank you.  Making it static works.

Comment: I have reverted your question. Once asked, do not change the question to something else. If you have a different issue, ask a different question. Edits should only be used to add clarification to the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Haldo pointed out in the comments the web method needed to be static.  The reason I didn't use static was because I was wanting to save a file in order to use the image.  This was resolved by returning a Base64 string and using that as image source.